# Track receving signals of parent process from a external process or child process

Tags: c, linux, signals, signal-processing, pid

I am having a parent process which spawns child process. After sometime my parent process got killed by receiving a signal. I want to track the receiving signals of parent process from my child process or external process by giving pid of a process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

static void hdl (int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    printf ("Sending PID: %ld, UID: %ld\n",
            (long)siginfo->si_pid, (long)siginfo->si_uid);
        fflush(stdout);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction act;

    memset (&act, '\0', sizeof(act));

    /* Use the sa_sigaction field because the handles has two additional parameters */
    act.sa_sigaction = &hdl;

    /* The SA_SIGINFO flag tells sigaction() to use the sa_sigaction field, not sa_handler. */
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror ("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1)
        sleep (10);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above program i am capturing signals sent by other process. Suppose i am spawing this from someother process and waits for signals.
Is there any way to track receiving signals of a parent process or else track received signals from other process.

Comment: Do you have control over how the process which's signal reception is to be monitored is started?

Comment: My child process is getting killed. so i want the child process to track receiving signals of parent or external process to track the parent receiving signals using parent's pid. Actually my parent Process is receiving SIGTERM.

Comment: "*My child process is getting killed.*" are you sure with that, as your question states: "*my parent process got killed*". Also you somehow did not answer my comment's question.

Comment: extremely sorry for that. its parent process...i don't have a control on parent process here